# NextJS/Webpack does not build node_module dependency with internal css

Tags: css, webpack, next.js

I have a couple of issues with a NextJS project that I believe might be solvable with a well built webpack configuration (However I am fairly new to webpack).

I am using `NextJS 8.0.3` with `@zeit/next-css 1.0.2-canary` in my local NextJS project, and I have a couple of npm installed dependencies that use css internally (styled reusable components).

The issue that I'm having is that I can't build or export my application because I get a CssSyntax error, and if I use `next-plugin-transpile-modules` it will build the installed node_modules dependencies but it won't load the css, because it does not build it.

This is the `next.config.js` file content, if you find the webpack part you will notice that it just uses the basic css-loader.

```
module.exports = withBundleAnalyzer(withCss({
  poweredByHeader: false,
  cssModules: false,
  // assetPrefix: APP_PREFIX, // This actually sets the path for getting static files somewhere else?*
  publicRuntimeConfig: { // Will be available on both server and client
    // pathPrefix: APP_PREFIX,
    cache: {
      static: {
        cdn: 3600,
        browser: 3600
      },
      dynamic: {
        cdn: 600,
        browser: 0
      }
    }
  },
  webpack: (config, { defaultLoaders }) => {

    // Fixes npm packages that depend on `fs` module
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: [
        'css-loader',
        'style-loader',
      ]
    });
    config.node = { fs: 'empty' }
    // console.log(config)
    return config
  },
  // bundle analyzer
  analyzeServer: ["server", "both"].includes(process.env.BUNDLE_ANALYZE),
  analyzeBrowser: ["browser", "both"].includes(process.env.BUNDLE_ANALYZE),
  bundleAnalyzerConfig: {
    server: {
      analyzerMode: 'static',
      reportFilename: '../bundles/server.html'
    },
    browser: {
      analyzerMode: 'static',
      reportFilename: '../bundles/client.html'
    }
  }
}))
```

My most immediate question is, what webpack loader or what pipeline configuration can I use so that webpack actually builds the css that is imported from the jsx dependency, and then build the component properly so that it's internal css and of course it's functionality are fully built.